# Does the order in which <link> tags or @import tags affect CSS selector specificity?

Tags: css

I have been operating under the impression that the order of `<link href="css">` tags in an html document have no bearing on the css engine's selector specificity, or that you should not count on that. For years, I put a class on the body to apply a "theme" to the body so that I can increase specificity by doing a contextual selector e.g.

```
body.theme h2 { color:red }
```

Can I rely solely on @import or  order in the head in order to establish an explicit specificity order?

Comment: The order matters for rules that have the same specificity.

Comment: If you have 2 CSS files with same selector but different values for the same property (like `a { color: red ; }` in the first and `a { color: blue ; }` in the second), then the second one override the first.

Comment: So, to apply the notion of a "Base" theme and then a more specific "Common" theme, I can rely on that.     <link href="css/js/1.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/ntheme/1.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/opm/main.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have two CSS file as such:

File named `BlueTheme.css` :

```
a  {
  color:Blue;
}
```

File named `RedTheme.css` :

```
a  {
  color:Red;
}
```

NOTE: Both of the aforementioned classes have the same specificity.

Now, let's say you have an HTML file as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BlueTheme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RedTheme.css">

<a href="#">Some link here</a>
<a href="#">Some other link here</a>
```

The result here would be that both of your hyperlinks would be Red.

If you were to make the following change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="RedTheme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BlueTheme.css">
```

in the HTML file (re-order the tags),

then the result here would be that both of your hyperlinks would be Blue.

I hope you got the gist of a scenario where the order of the link tag could affect the rendered HTML in terms of styling. :)